# Datetimepicker with fullCalendar preset hour

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, datetimepicker

I have bin searching around alot after to preset a hour and minutes in http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ datetimepicker, but still I cant get it working.

```
var start = $('#eventStart').datetimepicker({

     dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
     hour: 12,
     minute: 15,
     stepMinute: 15
});
```

and my inputfeald is an ordenary

My question is how to set a time like 12:15 with the current selected date from my fullCalendar

```
select: function(start, end, allvDay) {

     $('#eventStart').datepicker("setDate", new Date(start));
     $('#eventEnd').datepicker("setDate", new Date(end));
     $myCalendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
     $("#calEventDialog").dialog("option", "title", "Add Event");
     $('#calEventDialog').dialog('open');

  },
```

I getthis print in firebug "Error parsing the date string: Extra/unparsed characters found in date:  12:15"

anyone that can help me out,

//Tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem with your `date time format` .

Date time picker function taking the hours and minutes given by you and while parsing the date ,you didn't mention the corresponding fields in the `format` .

Please try change your `date format to "yy-mm-dd HH:mm"`

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Im not totaly with you here.

if I change my `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"` to `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd HH:mm" I get "2013-02-17 HH:02 00:00" 

And if I pas in 
`$('#eventStart').datepicker("setDate", new Date(start,18,00));`
Then I get it presetup but then the date is always todays date.

Im pretty new at jQuery and the datetimepicker. Cant get it right

Comment: still I get 

_Error parsing the date string: Extra/unparsed characters found in date:  09:00
date string = 2013-02-06 HH:02 09:00
date format = yy-mm-dd HH:mm_

Comment: check this issue once  here https://github.com/manfer/jQuery-DatePlusTime-Picker/issues/5

Comment: In the above link manfer commented that "But in the newer version you report yes the parseDate triggers an error: "Extra/unparsed characters found in date: xx:xx" and no matter the date format. I continue looking into this." ---i'm thinking that its an bug there ???do you agree ??

Comment: Yes look like it, as it doesent matter what format Im useing at all, have also triggerde a `timeFormat: HH:mm`but that doesnt make a sence.

Have tryed to manipulate the first trigger that initiates the datetimepicker befor my dialog pops up and then I got it right but it always puts up todays date insted.

Guess I have to make an issue on it. Thanks for the help Suresh Atta

Comment: No regreets.:) mark it as answer if its helpfull.so that someone may read all our conversation,who facing the same issue.

Comment: For those that facing the same problem have I put out the bug in the development forum as an issue.

Comment: Please paste that link and its really impressive  that feeling responsibility towards the community.

Comment: Dident think about that, you have a good point, here is the link:

https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/issues/551

Comment: See, now its confirm that its a bug in jq, some one there also have the same issue.hope soon we got a fix simmern.good luck.